# Merge two sub arrays

Tags: php

What is the best way to merge two arrays which contain sub arrays? Is there an function to do this and is it possible to do that without using `loop`? I have tried using function `array_merge_recursive`, but it's not doing what I need.

These are example arrays:

```
array1 = [
  [0] => [person] => [
    'name' => 'John'
  ],
  [1] => [person] => [
    'name' => 'Arya'
  ]
]

array2 = [
  [0] => [person] => [
    'surname' => 'Snow'
  ],
  [1] => [person] => [
    'surname' => 'Stark'
  ]
]
```

What I need:

```
array3 = [
  [0] => [person] => [
    'name' => 'John'
    'surname' => 'Snow'
  ],
  [1] => [person] => [
    'name' => 'Arya'
    'surname' => 'Stark'
  ]
]
```

But with above mentioned function I am getting array with 4 elements, two names and two surnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_map` with `array_merge`:

```
$array3 = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);
```

`array_map` calls a function on the corresponding elements of each of the input arrays. Then `array_merge` combines those sub-arrays.